# how to send the output of pprint module to a log file

Tags: python, logging

I have the following code:

```
logFile=open('c:\\temp\\mylogfile'+'.txt', 'w')
pprint.pprint(dataobject)
```

how can i send the contents of dataobject to the log file on the pretty print format ?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

```
with open("yourlogfile.log", "w") as log_file:
    pprint.pprint(dataobject, log_file)
```

See [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint).

Comment: This code above gives the following error: `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'pprint'`

the following works as intended:
`with open("yourlogfile.log", "w") as log_file:
    pprint.pprint(dataobject, log_file)`

Answer (score 26):

Please use `pprint.pformat`, which returns a formated string that can be dumped directly to file.

```
>>> import pprint
>>> with open("file_out.txt", "w") as fout:
...     fout.write(pprint.pformat(vars(pprint)))
...
```

Reference:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html

Comment: You will find pformat is much slower than pprint directly to the file, especially if you use a construct like `varname = %s % pprint.pformat(varname)`

Comment: pprint.pformat() is great because it can be used with standard logging as well. `logger.debug(pprint.pformat(varname))`

Answer (score 4):

For Python 2.7

```
logFile = open('c:\\temp\\mylogfile'+'.txt', 'w')
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4, stream=logFile)
pp.pprint(dataobject)   #you can reuse this pp.print
```